# How to compose nx devkit generators in a custom generator operating on the same tree?

Tags: javascript, nrwl-nx

im looking to create a custom generator that composes 2 nx/devkit generators and then adds some additional with a standard configuration. Im using the docs here https://nx.dev/extending-nx/recipes/local-generators  and here https://nx.dev/extending-nx/recipes/composing-generators
I have an automation plugin and some templates set up like this:

```
nx.json
package.json
etc...
- packages
  -- package1
  -- package2
- automation
  -- src
    -- generators / package-generator
      -- files
        -- config.template
        -- config2.template
```

When I invoke the generator, these files get created as expected.  When I add the devkit/libraryGenerator to try and compose these generators I get an error that says: `Cannot create a new project asdf at packages/asdf. It already exists.`   What seems to be happening is the generateFiles function is checking to see if the tree exists and throwing an error if it does instead of appending the new files to the existing (in memory?) tree created by the libraryGenerator. Here is my code:

```
import { addProjectConfiguration, formatFiles, generateFiles, Tree } from '@nx/devkit';
import * as path from 'path';
import { SomeGeneratorSchema } from './schema';
import { libraryGenerator } from '@nx/js';
import { configurationGenerator } from '@nx/storybook'


export async function SomeGenerator(tree: Tree, options: SomeGeneratorSchema) {
  const projectRoot = `packages/${options.name}`;
  addProjectConfiguration(tree, options.name, {
    root: projectRoot,
    projectType: 'library',
    sourceRoot: `${projectRoot}/src`,
    targets: {}
  });

  await libraryGenerator(
    tree, // virtual file system tree
    { name: options.name,
      unitTestRunner: 'jest' } // options for the generator
  );


  generateFiles(tree, path.join(__dirname, 'files'), projectRoot, options);
  await formatFiles(tree);
}

export default SomeGenerator;
```

So my question is how do i create a custom nx generator that composes generators creating files in the same folder directory?